# htaccess AuthType not allowed here, 500 internal server error

Tags: windows, apache, overriding

I need to configure a `.htaccess` file to override the `auth` settings.

However, I keep getting `"AuthType not allowed here"`.

I can't see what I did wrong. I've followed the steps provided on the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html) and tried some solutions from Google, but I cannot get this error to go away.

When I go to `http://localhost/test2` I get an `500 internal server error`. In the logs it shows `"AuthType not allowed here"`

This is my config `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory C:/apache24/htdocs/test2>
Options Indexes
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

.htaccess

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "Only for teachers"
AuthGroupFile C:/apache24/auth_groups
AuthUserFile C:/apache24/auth_users
Require group teachers
```

My `httpd.conf` file has all the required modules since it does work if I configure it directly via the httpd.conf file, however since this is school, the teacher wants us to use `.htaccess`. Everything works fine when I set up authentication directly in `httpd.conf`

Does anyone see what I've missed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to put `AuthType` in `<Directory>` section ( [more](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html) )

Comment: I removed AuthType from .htaccess and put it in the directory section, I'm still getting the same result

Comment: Try using http://shop.alterlinks.com/htaccess-validator/htaccess-validator.php to validate your entire `.htaccess`. Try also to run `apachectl configtest`. I wonder if your error comes from another `apache` config and not from `.htaccess` ?!?